# Does Enthought Canopy have an auto-complete and/or auto-suggest feature?

Tags: enthought, canopy

I am using the free version of Enthought Canopy for Python work and am forever finding myself hitting `Ctrl` + `Space` for an auto-complete list, but it never comes up.

It also doesn't auto-suggest anything whilst I type.

I have looked through all available settings and cannot find an option there to activate it.

Is this feature available and if so, how can one activate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ar
```

Immediately after `ar`, press the Tab key. What do you see?

Reference in User guide:
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#tab-completion

Comment: BTW, Canopy 2.0, due out around 1/1/2016, will include a new, more intelligent auto-completion mechanism (based on the great Jedi package).